String::from("1") => { - `fn` calls are not allowed in patterns
I tried to make a simple calculator in Rust, but an error occurred, I wanted to fix it, but then everything broke and I do not know how to fix all the bugs.
Code:
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter the number A");
    let mut num = String::new();
    let mut num2 = String::new();
    let mut num3 = String::new();
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut num) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Fatal error - {}", e);
        }
    }
    println!("Enter the number B");
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut num2) {
        Ok(_) => {

        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Fatal error - {}", e);
        }
    }
    println!("Choose 1 - +, 2 - -, 3 - *, 4 - /");
    match io::stdin().read_line(&mut num3) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Fatal error - {}", e);
        }
    }
    match num3 {
        String::from("1") => {
            num = num.trim().to_owned().parse().unwrap();
            println!("{}", num2 + &*num)
        },
        String::from("2") => {
            num = num.trim().to_owned().parse().unwrap();
            println!("{}", num2 - &*num)
        },
        String::from("3") => {
            num = num.trim().to_owned().parse().unwrap();
            println!("{}", num2 * &*num)
        },
        String::from("4") => {
            num = num.trim().to_owned().parse().unwrap();
            println!("{}", num2 / &*num)
        },
        _ => println!("Error")
    }
}

I searched the internet and read the documentation, but I still haven't figured anything out.
Error:
String::from("1") => {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `fn` calls are not allowed in patterns


Wouldn't it be more logical to first convert num3 to an integer, and then run the matche. Then you can output a different error/panic to the user in case the input is not an integer (i.e., not valid).

Matching to an enum (since these are four specific items / operations) might also be a good idea.

Finally, the easy way out might be to use match num3.as_str() and then simply use "1", "2" etc.
